# Is there any fork of OpenSolaris?

Tags: opensolaris

— I have a plan to use OpenSolaris in this year, but now, the development has been discontinued.

Answer (score 9):

First, OpenSolaris is not, nor related to, Linux. Solaris was primarily based on System V, which incorporated pieces of BSD code as well. Some concepts from SunOS, which was a fork of BSD 4.1, also were implemented in Solaris.

OpenSolaris has been discontinued, but Solaris is available for certain non-commercial, unsupported purposes for free. You can [download it from Oracle here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/solaris/downloads/index.html).

There are other alternatives however such as [OpenIndiana](http://openindiana.org) and [Illumos](http://www.illumos.org/).

Answer (score 5):

Since Oracle closed the source code tree during the development cycle, [Illumos](http://illumos.org) is the largest fork of the OpenSolaris codebase. [OpenIndiana](http://openindiana.org)'s current release is based on the latest dev code release of OpenSolaris. They ([OpenIndiana](http://openindiana.org)) have a development release that is based on [Illumos](http://illumos.org).

I don't know if [Schillix](http://schillix.berlios.de) is built off of [Illumos](http://illumos.org) yet, but it is also an option. And there's also [Nexenta](http://nexenta.org/), if you're looking for something with commercial support, and a strong focus on storage management.

If you are looking for something that is most similar to OpenSolaris, however, [Openindiana](http://openindiana.org) is it.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need access to source code then **the latest official Solaris 11 is still free** for *"developing, testing, prototyping and demonstrating your applications"* as [per its license](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/licenses/solaris-cluster-express-license-167852.html). Just download it and install

You can also find [ready-made VMs](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/solaris11/downloads/vm-templates-2245495.html) for use from Oracle